# How do I get service manager object in module.php file in zendframework 2?

Tags: zend-framework2

I found below function in module.php file of ZendFramework 2 module. I don't understand how do I get object of service manager($sm) in this function?

`

```
public function getControllerConfig()  
    {
        return array(  
             'initializers' => array(    
                function($instance, $sm){      
                      if($instance instanceof Service\FormServiceAwareInterface){  
                        $sm = $sm->getServiceLocator();
                        $formService = $sm->get('some_service');
                        $instance->setFormService($formService);
                      }
                 },
              ),
          );
      }
```

`

Can anyone explain how do I get object $sm in getControllerConfig function?

Answer (score 1):

When ZF2 start mvc process, all default services will be registered first.

Check manual you will know more about these services : http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.services.html

One of the most important services is *ModuleManager* which handle all modules related functions.

You could found *ModuleManager* start process in `Zend\Mvc\Service\ModuleManagerFactory->createService()`.

Notice these codes:

```
$serviceListener->addServiceManager(
    'ControllerLoader',
    'controllers',
    'Zend\ModuleManager\Feature\ControllerProviderInterface',
    'getControllerConfig'
);
```

This will call `Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->addServiceManager()` and save module name & method name for temporary.

Then when loadModule event triggered, `Zend\ModuleManager\Listener\ServiceListener->onLoadModule()` will be called. In this method, all returned results from `Modele->getControllerConfig()` will be register as service and put into `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager`.

Finally, when you call services from `getControllerConfig()`, `Zend\ServiceManager\ServiceManager->create()` will be called, instance and ServiceManager will be set into your Closure as parameters by:

```
foreach ($this->initializers as $initializer) {
    if ($initializer instanceof InitializerInterface) {
        $initializer->initialize($instance, $this);
    } elseif (is_object($initializer) && is_callable($initializer)) {
        $initializer($instance, $this);
    } else {
        call_user_func($initializer, $instance, $this);
    }
}
```

I wrote a note about [ZF2 Mvc process](http://avnpc.com/pages/zf2-mvc-process) before when ZF2 under beta3, maybe could help you (could use google translate).